# Padding Issues in Mozilla and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, padding

URL: http://onedirectionconnection.com

I am having padding issues with my website in Internet Explorer (as always)

In Chrome and Mozilla, the site is fine (at least in the latest versions). On internet explorer, the padding for my comments div doesn't work.

Basically, there is like 300px of padding on the left and something like 60 on the right, with the content are being 67 pxs so that the comment number can fit in the pink box at the bottom of each post.

In IE, the padding on the right does not render. If anyone knows what the problem could be, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what part of this page are we supposed to look at?

Comment: You should [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fonedirectionconnection.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) first.   IE hates invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in Quirks mode. There must be something wrong with your DOCTYPE.

#### Edit

Use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: If you hit F12 and change the document mode to IE9, IE8, or IE7, it works correctly.

Comment: Sorry I'm getting back to you so late (college got a bit hectic). I tried using this doctype and it created spaces in between my tables that were holding together my split image header. I'm currently going through the process of trying to validate my html and hopefully this will help...

Comment: You can't have anything above the DOCTYPE either. This includes comments and PHP code.

Comment: As for the spaces in between the tables, stop using tables for layout. Not only is it wrong, it's a pain to do. Use divs and CSS instead. Google "divs vs tables" and you'll get a ton of info about it.

Answer (score 0):

use this style maybe helpful

```
 html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Tried adding that snippet... still have the issue. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have a html comment block above the HTML

```
<!--THIS INCLUDES HEADER.PHP-->
```

This is throwing IE into Quirks mode. Remove this and see if it helps.

Comment: What is odd is that that comment is not in my actual header.php html. That comment doesn't appear until I upload my header and I'm not sure where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

First, use http://w3.validator.org to see if there is something wrong with your HTML. I also looked at your CSS, and there is no CSS reset. Internet Explorer doesn't follow the same box model and that's probably what is causing the issues. You should probably look into using the Eric Meyer reset for starters and then modify it to fit your needs. You can find the Eric Meyer reset here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/